# $other rule causes 3-way binding updates to db to fail

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a simple rule (below).  It looks pretty straightforward to me, and is modified based on the AngularFire seed.

My problem is with `$other`.  When I have it set to true, no fields in the users path are allowed to be updated (using 3-way binding).  When I have validate set to false, update works OK.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  All `$other` is supposed to do is disallow additional fields from appearing in the users path.  Any help is appreciated.

```
{
 "rules": 
 {
  ".read": false,
  ".write": false,

 "users": 
 {
    "$user": 
    {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
      ".write": "auth.uid === $user && (!newData.exists() || newData.hasChildren())",

        "firstName": 
        {
           ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        },

        "lastName": 
        {
           ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 2000"
        },   

        "$other": 
        {
           ".validate": false
        }            
    }  
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the "required" validation rules. Example:

```
".validate" : "newData.hasChildren(['firstName', 'lastName'])",
```

This should go before your `"firstName":` rule.

The idea is that you first set a general validation rule for all fields ensuring they are required. Then you create a validation rule for each field with the additional rules `newData.isString()` , `newData.val().length <= 2000` , `etc`

I had a similar issue and this blog post help me: https://calendee.com/2014/08/26/firebase-validation-haschildren-pro-tip/